if f,g are differentiable 'f(x)=g(x)+o(x^n) then is d/dx (f(x))=d/d(x) (g(x) ) +o(x^(n-1)) ''?
To illustrate my question, consider the following:
$$-\ln\lvert \cos(x)\rvert\ +c =\int\tan(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
($c=0$, $\tan (0)= 0$) than is it possible to evaluate the MacLaurin expansion of $\ln\lvert\cos(x)\rvert$ til a certain term and then evaluate its derivative to get the the expansion of $\tan(x)$? as doing that will lead to differentiating small $ d/dx (o(x^n) )$ in the process as the following shows:

\begin{align*}
-\ln(\cos x)=
&=-\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+o(x^6)\right) \\
&=-\left[\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{6!}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^3+o(x^6)\right] \\
&=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{16}{6!}x^6+\color{red}{o(x^6)}
\end{align*}
$$\Downarrow\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
\begin{align*}
\tan(x)
&=x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{16}{5!}x^5+\color{red}{o(x^5)} \\
&=x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5+o(x^5)
\end{align*}

The above is taken from this pdf written in french, on page 18.

It seems you are asking, if $f,g$ are differentiable and $f(x)=g(x)+o(x^6)$ then is $f'(x)=g'(x)+o(x^5)?$

You might need $f,g$ continuously differentiable.

Please check the identity at the top. I think you meant $\int tan (x), dx = -ln|cos(x)| + C$

exactly , I meant ∫tan(x)dx=−ln|cos(x)|+C  which I had corrected it . and maybe my question could be reformulated as you have said < if f,g are differentiable and ' f(x)=g(x)+o(x6) then is f′(x)=g′(x)+o(x5) ' > should I replace the Title of the  question by the Last statment .

Don't edit your question to a completely different one. Post a separate question!

Please read more carefully your pdf. they warn you twice that your statement is false, and is not what they are using. See p. 101 Attention : cela n’est pas obtenu en dérivant vraiment le développement car on ne sait rien dire sur la dérivation du terme $o(x^n)$. C’est
juste une application du théorème 4.19....

And again p. 106, on the example where you inserted unfaithfully an $\Downarrow\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ sign: On fera attention à la nuance suivante. Nous n’avons pas formellement dérivé
le premier développement pour obtenir le second car on ne sait rien dire sur la
dérivée du terme $o(x^6)$ (qui pourrait même ne pas être dérivable). Mais on sait
que les fonctions sont suffisamment régulières pour appliquer le théorème 4.19
(Taylor-Young) et celui-ci nous donne le lien entre les deux développements.

What vonbrand said.
Let $f(x) = x^5\sin\frac{1}{x}$.
Then
$$
f(x) = o(x^4)\quad\text{as } x\to 0
$$
but
$$
f'(x) \ne o(x^3)\quad\text{as } x\to 0
$$

What is true ... a power series may be differentiated term-by-term.
In your example, $-\ln(\cos x)$ is analytic near $x=0$, and you wrote some facts about its Maclaurin series, including consequences of differentiating it term-by-term.

thank you so much Vonbrand and GEdgar for your generous explaination , you had cleared my doubts

No. All $f(x) = o(x^n)$ tells you is that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) / x^n = 0$, $f(x)$ can very well have enormous derivatives. Think $f(x) = x^{n + 1} \sin(1/x)$

could you please elaborate more as what you have meant by 'f(x) has enormous derivatives '

You have the limit upside-down. Even better, put $1/x^n$ inside the sin.

$\mathcal{o}(x^n)$ just says that a term is bounded by some other function. Boundedness does not imply any information in general about derivatives

sorry , but this isn't what I'm asking for , I'm wondering the evaluation of                    d/dx  (o(x^6) ) ---> o(x^5) is allowed mathematically if so is  there any theorem that proves it? , as seen in the exemple its indeed the right expension tan(x)  but what theorem had we applied to arrive to such result ?

could we consider the fact that d/dx (o(x^n) ) <---> o(x^(n-1)) to be a  true equivalence ?
